# Method overridding in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [override of static method and final method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547349/override-of-static-method-and-final-method)

Will the sub class main method override super class main? Hope the main method in the super class gets executed.please explain

Comment: Please rephrase post and include relevant code.

Comment: Did you try this? What was the behavior?

Comment: Static methods cannot be overriden. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547349/override-of-static-method-and-final-method.

Comment: check this out (http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/can-static-methods-be-overridden/1)

Answer (score 3):

`main` method is `static` method and `static` methods are **not overridden**.

So if you are calling `Super.main(args[])` then `main` method of **super class** is called and if you are calling `Child.main(args[])` then `main` method of **child class** will be called.

Answer (score 1):

`Static method are not overridden`. Each class has its own static methods and they are never inherited so it will never get overridden as `main is static`